# How can I write this audio playing code nicer?

Tags: javascript

I want you to play it as many times as I click on it.

(1 sec long audio only.)

```js
function a() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('musicplay');
    var audio = document.getElementById('music');
    var playing = false;

    elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
        if (playing) {
            audio.play();
        } else {
            audio.play();
        }
        playing = !playing;
    });
}
```

Comment: `if (playing) { audio.play(); } else { audio.play(); }` makes no sense

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes you right, how can I write this nice? I am a beginner, so I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

```
function playMusic() {
    let playBtn= document.getElementById('musicplay');
    let audio = document.getElementById('music');
    let playing = false;

    playBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
        if (playing) {
            audio.pause();
            playing = !playing;
        } else {
            audio.play();
            playing = !playing;
        }

    });
}
```